# why init process is an user_space thread?

Tags: linux-kernel, init

init process is created by 0 process and its pid is 1. I have known it's the ancestor of all the other processes except 0 process. init process creates idle process for each cpu in smp system and execute /sbin/init.But why it's a user_space process? It's behavior is more like a kernel-thread.

Comment: If I am remember correctly there are two init process, one init is user space thread while other is kernel space thread. If I find code for the same, I will update it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no process with pid 0.

/sbin/init is userspace program and it is the first process launched by kernel if kernel command line does not have init= as an argument.

It is idle task not a process and it is not user-space process. init process does not create idle-task.